# SlidesJS hide pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am using Slidesjs to use a simple scroller on my site.  However, I cannot hide the pagination that shows the 1 and 2 bullet points.

I have tried trying to hide it in CSS and in a `Jquery.hide` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option built in, add these lines to where you fire the plugin:

```
pagination: false,
generatePagination: false
```

so your whole call would look like this (if you had no other otpions set, that is)

```
$(function(){
    $("#slides").slides({
        pagination: false,
        generatePagination: false
    });
});
```